# CS50: pset2 / initials:- I've got code that works but I feel like I am taking a shortcut with setting my array size

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

So I am working away on the 'less comfortable' version of the initials problem in CS50, and after beginning with very verbose code I've managed to whittle it down to this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int c = 0;

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string();
    int n = strlen(name);

    char initials[10];

    // first letter is always going to be the first initial
    initials[0] = name[0];

    // count through letters looking for spaces + add the first letter after a 
    // space to the initials array
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (name[j] == 32)
        {
            c += 1;
            initials[c] += name[j+1];
        }
    }    

    // print out initials
    for (int k = 0; k <= c; k++)
    {
        printf("%c", toupper(initials[k]));
    }    

   printf("\n"); 
}
```

As it stands like that it passes, but I feel like I am copping out a little cos I just pick [10] out of the air for the initial array size which I know isn't good practice. To make it a little 'better' I've tried to run a 'for' loop to iterate through the name string and add up the number of spaces. I then want to make the array [spaces + 1] as if there are 2 spaces then there will be 3 initials. The code I am trying for that is:

```
string name = get_string();
int n = strlen(name);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (name[i] == 32)
    {
        spaces +=1;
    } 

}
```

The thought is that I then make 'char initials[spaces + 1]' on the next line, but even before I can do that, compiling my code with just this 'for' loop returns a fail when I upload it for checking (although it compiles no problem). Even if I don't use any of the 'for' loops output the mere fact it is there gives me this error.

Where am I going wrong?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even have to store? Just print it then and there....

Comment: Otherwise, my bet, figure out the number of elements and go with VLA.

Comment: `char* initials = malloc(spaces+1);` Use just like your array but call `free(initials);` when you are done using it.

Comment: When you try `char initials[spaces +1];` do you get compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: If you have a line containing '`john q doe`', there are 2 spaces, but three words to convert to initials, so you need an array of size 4 to allow for the terminal null byte — that's the number of spaces plus 2.  You should use `' '` to represent space, not `32`.

Comment: It is okay to use a small buffer; most peoples' names don't have many initials. But if you do so, you must enforce that limit: Only add new initials if you are sure that your char array can hold them. Make sure you leave one charat the end to hold the null terminator.

Comment: Also, related to *cs50.h*, you need to free the string `name`. This is the reference - [get_string](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string)

Comment: Note that it would be feasible not to store the initials.  Simply print the upper-case version of the letter as you identify that the character should be an initial.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, keep in mind that execution speed is most often more valuable than memory use. If you first go look for spaces and after that allocate memory, you have to iterate through the array twice. This is an optimization of memory use at the cost of execution speed. So it might make more sense to just allocate a "large enough" array of lets say 100 characters and keep the code that you have.

> I then want to make the array [spaces + 1] as if there are 2 spaces then there will be 3 initials

Keep in mind that C strings are null terminated, so you need to allocate room for the null terminator too, `spaces + 1 + 1`.

> compiling my code with just this 'for' loop returns a fail when I upload it for checking (although it compiles no problem). Even if I don't use any of the 'for' loops output the mere fact it is there gives me this error.

What error? Does it compile or does it not compile, your text is contradicting.

Make sure you initialize `spaces` to zero.

---

As a side note, never use "magic numbers" in C code. `if (name[i] == 32)`, 32 is gibberish to anyone who can't cite the ASCII table by memory. In addition, it is non-portable to systems with other symbol tables that might not have the same index numbers. Instead write:

```
if (name[i] == ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a good approach to cater for such situations is the one the library function `snprintf` uses: It requires you to pass in the string to fill and the size of that string. In ensures that the string isn't overwritten and that the string is zero-terminated.

The function returns the length of the characters written to the string if the had the string been large enough. You can now do one of two things: Guess a reasonable buffer size and accept that the string will be cut short occasionally. Or call the function with a zero length, use the return value to allocate a char buffer and then fill it with a second call.

Applying this approach to your initials problem:

```
int initials(char *ini, int max, const char *str)
{
    int prev = ' ';         // pretend there's a space before the string
    int n = 0;              // actual number of initials

    while (*str) {
        if (prev == ' ' && *str != ' ') {
            if (n + 1 < max) ini[n] = *str;
            n++;
        }

        prev = *str++;
    }

    if (n < max) {
        ini[n] = '\0';
    } else if (max > 0) {
        ini[max] = '\0';
    }    

    return n;
}
```

You can then either use the fixed-size bufer approach:

```
char *name = "Theodore Quick Brown Fox";

char ini[4];
initials(ini, sizeof(ini), name);

puts(ini);        // prints "TQB", "F" is truncated
```

Or the two-step dynamic-size approach:

```
char *name = "Theodore Quick Brown Fox";
int n;

n = initials(NULL, 0, name);

char ini[n + 1];
initials(ini, sizeof(ini), name);

puts(ini);        // prints "TQBF"
```

(Note that this implementation of `initals` will ignore multiple spaces and spaces at the end or at the beginning of the string. Your look-one-ahead function will insert spaces in these cases.)

Answer (score 0):

You know your `initials` array *can't* be any bigger than the name itself; at most, it can't be more than half as big (every other character is a space).  So use that as your size.  The easiest way to do that is to use a variable-length array:

```
size_t n = strlen( name ); // strlen returns a size_t type, not int

char initials[n/2+1];         // n/2+1 is not a *constant expression*, so this is
                              // a variable-length array.
memset( initials, 0, n + 1 ); // since initials is a VLA, we can't use an initializer
                              // in the declaration.
```

The only problem is that VLA support may be iffy - VLAs were introduced in C99, but made optional in C2011.

Alternately, you can use a dynamically-allocated buffer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
size_t n = strlen( name );

char *initials = calloc( n/2+1, sizeof *initials ); // calloc initializes memory to 0

/**
 * code to find and display initials
 */

free( initials );  // release memory before you exit your program.
```

Although, if all you have to do is *display* the initials, there's really no reason to store them - just print them as you find them.

Like others have suggested, use the character constant `' '` instead of the ASCII code `32` for comparing against a space:

```
if ( name[j] == ' ' )
```

or use the `isspace` library function (which will return true for spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.):

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if ( isspace( name[j] ) )
```