# Attempt to configure program to return initals from string in C, encountering segmentation error

Tags: c, cs50

So here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
   // creates variable string equal to input from user
   printf("what name?\n");
   string s = get_string();
   int n = strlen(s);


if (s != NULL)
{
    // iterates through string
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // checks string for space, if so adds to iterator to skip char
        while(s[i] == 32)
        {
            i++;
        }

        // checks if string is greater than or equal to 'A'
        if(s[i] >= 'A')
        {
            // prints Char and it's integer, then adds to iterator
            printf("%c", s[i]);
            i++;
            do {
                i++;
            } while (s[i] != 32);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can't think of anyways to separate the two words into different indexes, I've tried using '\0'. Any help is highly appreciated. I'm really trying to learn and understand where I'm going wrong with this. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: First observation, you should check `if (s != NULL)` *before* calling `int n = strlen(s);`

Comment: It's not clear what you want this code to do. If you give it *"D'Yayo Anthony"*, do you want it to print "DA" or "DYA"?

Comment: Second observation, you are tampering with `i` within the `for` loop which is controlled by `i`, and `while (s[i] != 32);` does not check for end of string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930700/cs50-pset2-initials-ive-got-code-that-works-but-i-feel-like-i-am-taking-a

Comment: Try `isalpha()`.

Comment: Thank you Weather Vane!! isalpha() did the trick! I'll be sure to update the order of that if expression as well, so that its before the strlen

Answer (score 0):

This is the part where you're **really, really** going wrong:

```
        do {
            i++;
        } while (s[i] != 32);
```

As an example to explain why this will most of the time result in a Segmentation fault, let's say the user entered `John`. Then `s` would be an `char` array, 5 element long containing `'J'`, `'o'`, `'h'`, `'n'` and `'\0'`. This would happen:

- Inside your for loop, your code would find `'J'` in `s[0]` and display it.
- Then it would increase `i` to `1`.
- Then it would enter your `do` loop.
- Then in would increase `i` to `2` and compare `s[2]` (which is `'h'`) to `32`.
- Since `'h'` is not equal to `' '` it would repeat that loop, increasing `i` to `3` and compare `s[3]` (which is `'n'`) to `32` (which is the same as `' '`).
- Since `'n'` is not equal to `32` it would repeat that loop, increasing `i` to `4` and compare `s[4]` (which is `'\0'`) to `32`.
- Since `'\0'` is not equal to `32` it would repeat that loop, increasing `i` to `5` and compare `s[5]` (which is past the end of the array) to `32`.
- And then it would continue repeating that loop, going further and further into memory it should not be going into until either it finds an `32` by pure chance or you get a Segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was definitely seeing that behavior and was lost. I really appreciate you breaking this down for me.